# How to route select e-mails from Office 365 to another SMTP Server

Tags: email, smtp, microsoft-office-365, sap

I have set up an SAP system to act as an SMTP server on port 25000.

The company uses Office 365 as its email provider.

Is it possible to route/forward e-mails that are delivered to a specific e-mail account from the Office 365 server to the SAP SMTP server?

e.g.

- andrew@mycompany.com -> Office 365 e-mail system
- brian@mycompany.com -> Office 365 e-mail system
- charlie@mycompany.com -> Office 365 e-mail system
- **sapuser@mycompany.com**  -> Office 365 e-mail system  **-> SAP SMTP server**
- david@mycompany.com -> Office 365 e-mail system
- edward@mycompany.com -> Office 365 e-mail system

Comment: What do you mean under *SAP SMTP server*? AFAIK, SAP is bundled with no SMTP mail server and requires external one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to route select e-mails from Office 365 to another SMTP Server, at least not an SAP SMTP server.

I ended up forwarding e-mails from one domain to another - using the second domain as an 'SAP e-mail only domain', which would be routed to the SAP e-mail server:

**sapuser@mycompany.com** -> **sapuser@sapmycompany.com** -> **SAP SMTP server**

This way, people are able to send e-mails to the company, using the companies proper domain. The e-mails then get routed to another domain (which people don't see) and the e-mail gets received by the SAP system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. MS call in "Conditional mail routing in Exchange Online".

1. Set up a connector from Office 365 to your email server.
2. Create a mail flow rule that'll send mail to it based on the criteria you define.

There is links about that:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/set-up-connectors-to-route-mail

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/conditional-mail-routing

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can.

To summrize the steps, you need to:

1. Create a contact inside Exchange.
2. Mail-Enable the contact you just created.
3. Enable mail forward from the users to the newly created contact.

The steps are well documented in this Microsoft Knowledge Base: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281926

Note that there might be some step variations, but the idea are essentially the same.

Comment: Unfortunately the article only describes how to forward e-mails to another Exchange server, non an SAP SMTP server.

From the KB:
'This article describes how to configure a mailbox to forward mail to either a mail-enabled contact (a custom recipient in Exchange Server 5.5) or another mailbox on an Exchange 2000 computer or on an Exchange Server 2003 computer.'

Comment: See those lines you just copied pasted? take a closer look at the words "a mail-enabled contact", this is what you need to make this trick work.